# shell script to append ID for newusers command

Tags: shell-script, scripting

I am in the process of creating 60 users locally in a linux machine. I wanted to do it automatically and so I found I can use the newusers command to add the users in batch. I have the users and password list a text file. Currently, I have the text file in the below format.

```
user1:password1
user2:password2
user3:password3
```

However, for the newusers command, I need to have the file in the following format.

```
user1:password1:1011:1000:user1:/home/user1:/bin/bash
```

I need to modify the text file to append the UID, group ID and the user home path and the user shell. Is there an easier way than this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modifying the file is easy enough, just loop through your `username:pass` file:

```
k=1000; while IFS=: read user pass; do 
             echo "$user:$pass:$k:1000:/home/$user:/bin/bash"; let k++;
        done <  users.txt > newusers.txt
```

This will create a file called `newusers.txt` with the following content:

```
user1:password1:1000:1000:/home/user1:/bin/bash
user2:password2:1001:1000:/home/user2:/bin/bash
user3:password3:1002:1000:/home/user3:/bin/bash
```

Comment: it creates the newusers.txt file as expected. But I am getting an error as, **bash: 1=1000: command not found **. Also, the value of $k is assigned from 1.

Comment: @Ramesh I think I see. The `$` in my answer represents the prompt, it should not be included when you run it. See updated answer.